# Проблема с thymeleaf,WebMvcConfigurer и запуском web-страницы

Tags: spring-mvc

Прохожу курс по Spring и застрял на том, что у меня никак не получается открыть web страницу. Если конфигурировать через web.xml,то всё нормально будет работать. Но если через java-код,то ошибок никаких не будет, даже в логах всё хорошо, но никакие сайты открываться не буду, а будет выскакивать ошибка 404. Всё делается через TomCut 9.0.73 ,уже и перезапускать пробовал, и другие версии качал - ничего не помогает. В курсе даже не добавляется зависимость jakarta.servlet-api,но если я её не добавляю, то выскакивает ошибка о том, что не находятся необходимые файлы.
Сама конфигурация происходит через два java класса, которые будут прикреплены первыми.

```
public class SpringMvcDispatcherServletInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    return null;
}

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    return new Class[]{SpringConfig.class};
}

@Override
protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    return new String[]{"/"};
}}


public class SpringConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

private final ApplicationContext applicationContext;

@Autowired
public SpringConfig(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
    this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
}
@Bean
public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
    SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
    templateResolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
    templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
    templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
    return templateResolver;
}

@Bean
public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
    SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
    templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
    templateEngine.setEnableSpringELCompiler(true);
    return templateEngine;
}

@Override
public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
    ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
    resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
    registry.viewResolver(resolver);
}}
```

В pom.xml добавлены зависимости
Spring: context,core,mvc,WebMvc 6.0.3 версии
Thymeleaf 3.1.1 версии
Javax.servlet-api 4.0.1 и jakarta.servlet-api 6.0.0.
Версия Maven 1.9

[image: И,думаю,структура проекта тоже пригодится.]

Comment: [Почему в вопросе не следует выкладывать скриншоты кода/данных/ошибок?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119/#12120)